# Youtube Title scrapping Selenium automation

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I have been trying to scrap the list of video titles of one particular channel using the selenium web driver. The code is executed successfully without any errors. Once I returned the titles but after It shows only blank title names.

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")

search_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input")
search_element.click()
search_element.send_keys("statquest")
search_element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

enter_channel = driver.find_element(By.ID,'main-link').click()
video_tab = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//\*\[@id="tabsContent"\]/tp-yt-paper-tab\[2\]").click()

video_title = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"style-scope ytd-rich-grid-renderer")
time.sleep(10)
for i in video_title:
row = i.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"style-scope ytd-rich-grid-media")
for j in row:
title = j.find_element(By.ID,"video-title").text
print(title)
driver.quit()
```

I tried this code. It did not return any error. But It returned a blank line. I do not know what is happening but once it was working but now it is not. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Edit the question with the correct indentation.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly go to the target channel's videos. Here's how

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

channel_id = "statquest"
driver.get(f"https://www.youtube.com/@{channel_id}/videos")

container = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'contents')
videos_blocks = container.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'ytd-rich-grid-row')

for block in videos_blocks:
    videos = block.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'ytd-rich-item-renderer')
    for video in videos:
        title = video.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'h3').text
        print(title)

time.sleep(2)
```

output:

```
The Ukulele: Clearly Explained!!!
Word Embedding and Word2Vec, Clearly Explained!!!
The AI Buzz, Episode #5: A new wave of AI-based products and the resurgence of personal applications
CatBoost Part 2: Building and Using Trees
...........
Introduction to Coding Neural Networks with PyTorch and Lightning
Three more lessons from my Pop!!!
Recurrent Neural Networks (RNNs), Clearly Explained!!!
The StatQuest Illustrated Guide To Machine Learning, Theme Song!!!
```

Note that if you want to scrape all the available videos, you'll need to first scroll down to the bottom to load all the video contents.